# How to export a jar with only the dependencies that are set to export in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, dependencies

So, I have my code, along with some dependencies/libraries.

I have some of the libraries set to export (things like JSON and a different jar that I have made), and some not (JUnit mainly).

When I go to Rclick project > export > java > Jar File, it doesn't add any of the libraries.

When I go to Rclick project > export > java > Runnable Jar File, it adds EVERY library.

How do I make a jar file with only the dependencies that I choose?